# RandomForest in R: Bad performance even on training set

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I'm trying to run a RandomForest for a regression. However, it does not perform well even on the training set, not to mention the test set. 
I'm now wondering whether this is caused by a bad quality of the input data, or if I still can improve something in my algorithm?

Here is my model:

- n=430
- 2 continuous input variables
- 1 categorical input variable
- 1 continuous output variable

**Formula (caret package)**:

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number=10, repeats = 3, verbose = TRUE, savePredictions = TRUE)
fit<-train(x=train_parametres, y=train_result,
           data=analyse,
           method="rf",
           trControl=control,
           importance=TRUE,
           allowParallel=TRUE,
           ntree=2000
)
```

**Output** (results for "fit" from cross-validation on training set):

```
Random Forest 

324 samples
  3 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 292, 292, 292, 291, 292, 291, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  RMSE     Rsquared 
  2     4983092  0.5596401
  3     5128162  0.5452369

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

Changing nodesize, ntree and mtry does not alter the results very much.
Is it thus a problem of data quality, or are there some other possibilities to improve the model which I have overlooked, e.g. through data normalization? To my understanding, it should at least be possible to overfit the model a bit, so that I'd get at least better results for the training set ...

Comment: Have you rather tried https://datascience.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Without a clue of your data, how exactly are we supposed to offer any opinion here?